# DPRP_DISABLED exception after upgrading to pro

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, recurring-billing

I'm integrating the "Payments REST API" to setup billing agreements on my site and I'm having issues where I probably should not.

Using a sandbox merchant account, I've successfully authorized a payment through the REST API. The payment was accepted and "Notification of payment received" shows up in the test account's notifications.

Then, I created a new sandbox merchant account and in the "Profile" tab, I upgraded the account type from "BUSINESS" to "BUSINESS-Pro". I then created a new REST API application with this test account. Yet, when I try creating a billing plan, activate that plan and then create a billing agreement with that plan, I'm thrown a "DPRP_DISABLED" exception. I've learned that this "Direct Payment Recurring Payments" exception is for when the account type is not set to "BUSINESS-Pro", but as I previously stated, mine is.

I've tried creating multiple other accounts with the "BUSINESS-Pro" type. I even tried setting one's country to the UK (instead of US), but no luck.

Should this be happening?

Comment: DPRP doesn't use REST, it uses DoDirectPayment, or technically, it uses CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, so I'm a little confused.  Are you sure you're using REST, or are you using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile in the classic API?

Comment: I'm definitely using REST. I also tried the Merchant API with a similar DPRP error. Do you think it'd fix the issue if my paypal.com account were upgraded to pro (for $30/month)? @AndrewAngell

Comment: Again, Pro uses the DoDirectPayment / CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile APIs, which are not part of REST.  So no, upgrading to Pro won't help you if you're using REST.  Personally, I would recommend you go ahead and upgrade to Pro, but use the Classic API instead of REST.  If you're using PHP I have a class library that would make those calls very quick and easy.

Comment: I went with Stripe and was good to go in a few minutes. I may lose a few dedicated Paypal users, but it's a trade-off I'm willing to make. @AndrewAngell

Comment: That's great for credit cards.  I would still highly recommend adding PayPal itself as an option.  You will definitely lose sales otherwise.

Comment: Definitely, and if I find it difficult to reach my monthly lead conversion goal, I'll make it a priority sooner rather than later. Thanks for your time. @AndrewAngell